# Laptop CPU fan replacement of Lenovo Z500

Tags: laptop

I've just upgraded my Lenovo Z500's RAM to 2x8GB a few days ago and while doing that I've cleaned the fan as well. After that the fan started rattling although at random times it just becomes quiet. I don't know how many times I've opened it again to check whether it was touching something, I couldn't find it. So my conclusion was that there is a problem with the fan itself.

I want to change the fan but I don't know what specs I am supposed to look for.

This rattling sound is unbearably annoying. Below is a picture of the fan I took. Here is the [hardware maintenance manual](https://download.lenovo.com/consumer/mobiles_pub/ideapad_z500p500_hmm_1st_edition_sep_2012_english.pdf) but I could only find `VIWZ2 Fan` listed in the parts list. This might probably be difficult to find as this laptop is around 8 years old.

Could you please help me?

[image: Lenovo Z500 CPU Fan Picture]

Answer (score 2):

From some googleing, I found a replacement fan: https://nl.grandado.com/products/ssea-cpu-cooling-fan-voor-lenovo-z400-z400a-z500-z500a-p500-z410-z510

I don't know if that webshop ships internationally though

Comment: I tried translating using Google translate, though I couldn't find anything about international shipping I found that they mention "Long shipping" so that might mean they ship internationally I guess. :D I'll see if I can find anything that can be shipped earlier because I can't bear this noise, if not I'll probably order from that shop. Thank you!

Comment: its more like free shipping probably...